# To download selected filename in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the below code i get attachment file names in a session i have bind the documnetid,attachmentname and download.but when i select 1st attachmnet filename it is downloading second attchmt filename.My aim is to download what i select in grid view.
eg

```
document id  attchfilename   download
1             xxx               view
2             yyy               view
```

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="Attchdwnld" runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="true" 
        AllowSorting="true"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CellPadding="4" 
        CssClass="mGrid" 
        ForeColor="#333333" 
        PageSize="10" 
        PageSize-Mode="NumericPages"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
        PagerStyle-Visible="true" 
        ShowFooter="false" 
        Width="100%"
        OnRowCommand="Attchdwnld_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DocumentID" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="DocumentID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DocumentID") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AttachmentFileName" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="AttachmentFileName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AttachmentFileName") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DownLoad" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnlbtnAttch" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="Edit">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Attchdwnld_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
    lblMessage.Text = SearchDoc.AttachmentFileName;
    string fileurl = "C:\\Search\\" + stName + "\\" + strtFolder + "\\" + lblMessage.Text;
    string filename = fileurl;
    if (filename != "")
    {
        string path = filename;
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are setting value of `Session["Documentname"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you should store `Session["Documentname"]` in your code at all. So I am omitting that part.

Try this code

```
protected void Attchdwnld_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // gets the clicked row of your GridView
    var row = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    //gets the filename in the cliked row
    var attachmentNameLabel = row.FindControl("AttachmentFileName") as Label;
    //store it to lblMessage's Text
    lblMessage.Text = attachmentNameLabel.Text;
    var filePath = String.Format("C:\\Search\\{0}\\{1}\\{2}",
        stName, strtFolder, lblMessage.Text);

    var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error? does file exist? on which browser are you testing it? also what you get displayed in `lblMessage.Text`